# video.js requestFullScreen on android 4

Tags: javascript, android, video, video.js, android-fullscreen

I try to get a video.js video playing fullscreen by the click/tap on a button.
It's working fine on any iOS device. But on Android (testing this on 4.1.2 on a Galaxy S4) the video plays, but won't enter fullscreen. Any idea how to get fullscreen on Android? Thanks!

This is the code I use for the fullscreen change:

```
$('.slider .icon-play').click(function () {
                videojs("mobileVideo").ready(function () {
                    var myPlayer = this;
                    myPlayer.currentTime(0);
                    myPlayer.play();
                    myPlayer.on("loadedmetadata", function () {
                        this.requestFullScreen();
                        myPlayer.on("play", function () {
                            this.requestFullScreen();
                        });
                    });
                    myPlayer.on("ended", function () {
                        this.cancelFullScreen();
                    });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

this.requestFullScreen();

needs to be called from a user driven event.

see

[Video.js enter fullscreen on play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143720/video-js-enter-fullscreen-on-play)

Comment: but isn't the click function an user driven event?

Comment: The click event is yes, but you have the event being called from the `myPlayer.on("play")` that is being called from `myPlayer.on("loadedmetadata")`. So the click event isn't calling the requestFullScreen it is adding an event listener that isn't user diriven.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you! I'll try that out as soon as I can :)