# VideoJS autoplay and fullscreen on Pageloading

Tags: jquery, html, video

I am trying to start Videoplayer VideoJS on the .html Page with autoplay in fullscreen.
Somehow "autoplay" doesnt works. Has anyone idea?

```
 <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="true" style="max-width: 90%; margin: 0 auto 0 auto;" 
                        width="100%" height="100%"
  poster=""
  data-setup="{"controls": true,  "autoplay": true, "preload": auto, "customControlsOnMobile": true}">
<source src="Z3_Kopf_Web_k.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<source src="Z3_Kopf_Web_k.webm" type='video/webm' />
<source src="Z3_Kopf_Web_k.flv" type='video/flv' />
<source src="Z3_Kopf_Web_k.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
<track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
<track kind="subtitles" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
```

Comment: Use this autoplay preload="auto"

Comment: <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="true" autoplay preload="auto"> like this

Comment: is any params in data-setup for FullScreen?

Comment: autoplay preload="auto" works just in Browsers. is any solution for IOS/Android ?

Comment: iOS browsers don't support playback before any human interaction. Autoplay just does not work, and there has to be a touch/click event before initiating playback via the API. Android browsers now follow that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
autoplay preload="auto"
```

As you asked about the **fullscreen** that wont be possible or right way of doing that, because for security and good user experience, **browsers will only let you trigger full screen inside a user-triggered event**, like a 'click'. You can't have every web page going to full screen as soon as you visit it, and you can cause a video to start playing automatically, which would violate that rule. So you need to move this to a 'click' handler on the actual play button.

[Source Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17170450/1787416)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to go to fullscreen without user interaction. This is a security feature implemented by browsers.

You can only go to fullscreen when there is a user interaction or a device orientation change.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen