# HTML5 Video Player FullScreen Issue

Tags: javascript, html

We publish video on Wordpress site. We created a embed codes with iframe. When i open iframed page fullscreen work with normally. But video inside of iframe on page, fullscreen don't work. Because full width and height relative to iframe. What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you run the IFrame source in the new tab it doesn't open in the IFrame.
when dealing with video that is delivered via iframe. Setting a height is required, otherwise browsers will render the iframe at a static height of 150px, which is far too squat for most video and makes for more Ridiculous and Embarrassing.

Here is what you can do:

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .videoContainer {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        padding-top: 25px;
        height: 0;
    }
    .videoContainer iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="videoContainer">
        <iframe scrolling="no" width="640" height="360" src="http://video.localhost/embed?video=HLuUyE9-qcA&width=640&yukseklik=360&kali‌​te=medium&vidp=11783" style="overflow: hidden;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With this technique, you wrap the video in another element which has an intrinsic aspect ratio, then absolute position the video within that. That gives us fluid width with a reasonable height we can count on.

Comment: why? fullscreen button in iframe. my player created by javascript.

Comment: Can you post the sample embed code here, so that we will have more clarity

Comment: Example: `<iframe scrolling="no" width="640" height="360" src="http://video.localhost/embed?video=HLuUyE9-qcA&width=640&yukseklik=360&kalite=medium&vidp=11783" style="overflow: hidden;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Because when you run the IFrame source in the new tab it doesn't open in the IFrame.

Comment: thanks for helps. I update my codes with your tips. This is working. But it can sizing of full to my parent div. No full to screen. What can i do now? Parent div has `width:700px; float:left;`  only.

Comment: So you want to ignore the dimensions specified for the parent width, and set video to full screen irrespective of any parent DIV

Comment: Yes sizing to all of screen.

Comment: You can test with my example link in Firefox, Chrome.. Problem is only in IE

Comment: But in your example the parent width is 640px. Am I right ??

Comment: Video width is **640px**, parent div width is **700px**

Comment: @FatihSARI I have checked that you are using videojs in your application, you should check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143720/video-js-enter-fullscreen-on-play) post.

Comment: You are great! Thanks for everythink @Veer. This was very important problem. Thanks again. Good coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68161/discussion-between-fatih-sari-and-veer).